# Compute for the nth item from the code range of 000A to ZZZZ

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to compute for the **nth** item from a range of code? The code 000A can go up to ZZZZ. The rule of the 4 characters is that is starts from 0 then the next values would be from A to Z except for the last character since it starts with A instead of zero (000A).

---

Eg.

1st: 000A

2nd: 000B

...

27th: 00AA

28th: 00AB

...

475,254th: ZZZZ

---

**475,254** was identified to be the last through this computation since there are 26 letters in the alphabet:

(26 ^ 4) + (26 ^ 3) + (26 ^ 2) + (26 ^ 1) = 475,254

---

How can I compute for the 450,700th for example? Thank you~

Comment: I see this as similar to converting from one number base to another. So modulus and remainder are your friends, here, and you must work backwards.

Comment: It's best to start with some numerical examples. Let's start with the string NASA. N is the 14th letter in the alphabet, A is the 1st and S is the 19th letter. Therefore, the position in the list is
$$
14 \cdot 26^3  + 1 \cdot 26^2 + 19\cdot 26^1 + 1 \cdot 26^0 = 247~235
$$
Then, we want to work backwards to get the original string. The last letter can be easily obtained by calculating the remainder of $247~235$ divided by $26$:
$$
\frac{247~235}{26} = 9~509 + 1~\text{remainder}
$$
Therefore, the last letter is A. Now, we want to see what is $9~509$ divided by $26$... Can you continue?

Comment: I got it Sir @MattiP :) If you could submit this comment as an answer, I'd gladly accept it. Thank you~